# Connecting the Android app to PHP,MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to connect the android app to PHP file and SQL database, but the app just gets stopped, no response at all.

Here is Java code:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

And Here is JSONParser.java

```
 package com.example.androidhive;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.util.Log;

 public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params,     "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

And Here is php code

```
 <?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
 $response = array();


 // include db connect class
 require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

 // connecting to db
 $db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    $product["price"] = $row["price"];
    $product["description"] = $row["description"];
    $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
    $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];



    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Does your PHP script run if you call it directly? Any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: One thing I immediately spotted is there should be a space between the * and FROM in the SQL query in PHP.

Comment: While debugging, at which line does the exception raise ?

Comment: This does not look it has anything to do with android but with PHP. In future please consider exactly what you are asking and what the precise issues are.

Comment: thank you all, the php pages are working well but there is problem in connecting between the app and database, this was shown in logcat of the app

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());
```

should contain a space between the * and FROM.

Your Android code is expecting a result from the server which does not come. That is where your code hangs on.

Check the server log of MySQL.

Comment: Is there any setting that I should done it with the wamp server or with the Java EE?

Answer (score 0):

ok thank you all, I just figure it out .
I should use //10.0.2.2/ instead of 127.0.0.1

thanks